# recursive find some 'foo' and tar

Tags: bash, tar

Consider the following folder structure

```
 root/dirA/the_folder
 root/dirA/dir2/the_folder
 root/dirB/the_folder
 root/dirB/dir2/the_folder
```

I want to recursively find and tar the `dirA/the_folder` and `dirB/the_folder`. However when I use

```
find root/ -name 'the_folder' -type d | xargs tar cvf myTar.tar
```

It will pack all folders (containing dir2/the_folder) and I don't want that. What is the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, wouldn't just this be enough?

```
tar cfv mytar.tar root/*/the_folder/
```

Comment: Simpler, and works as well. Just not as generic. But thanks for showing the forest I didn't see for all those trees. ;-) +1

Comment: @DevSolar `tar` (well, at least the GNU version) possesses incredible filtering possibilities! together with bash globs, it nearly renders `find` useless.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: This is more a demonstration of [tag:Bash]'s [tag:globbing], rather than [tag:tar]'s filtering.

Comment: @Johnsyweb who said it was showing `tar`'s filtering abilities? `:)` you're right this is just a simple bash globbing!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Since `find` can be used in many contexts other than gathering input files for `tar`, it's a bit much to say that `tar`'s options could render `find` "nearly useless". I'd actually claim the opposite: It's more effective to learn `find`'s options for your generic "input file gathering" needs than learning about the options of `tar`, `grep`, `sed`, `bash` globbing etc. etc. -- but I get your point. In this *specific* context your solution is superior to mine. Mine, however, works *regardless* of what you intend to do with the so-identified files. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-maxdepth` option of `find` to limit the recursion depth:

```
find root/ -maxdepth 2 -name 'the_folder' -type d
```

Try `man find` for *lots* of useful options that `find` offers. You will be surprised. For example, you can do away with the `| xargs` by using `find`'s `-exec` option:

```
find root/ -maxdepth 2 -name 'the_folder' -type d -exec tar cvf myTar.tar {} +
```